# Hierarchical block <g3> is unconnected in block <main>

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

Please help me figure out the warning in this code.

Rest of the warnings:

> WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <g3> is unconnected in block <main>.
>   It will be removed from the design.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <g2> is unconnected in block <main>.
>   It will be removed from the design.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <g4> is unconnected in block <main>.
>   It will be removed from the design.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <cell_out_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 1 in block <game_logic>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:3002 - This design contains one or more registers/latches that are directly
>   incompatible with the Spartan6 architecture. The two primary causes of this is
>   either a register or latch described with both an asynchronous set and
>   asynchronous reset, or a register or latch described with an asynchronous
>   set or reset which however has an initialization value of the opposite 
>   polarity (i.e. asynchronous reset with an initialization value of 1).

The main module:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
use work.game_package.all;

entity main is
    PORT(   clk: in std_logic;
            reset: in std_logic;
            pressed_left:in std_logic;
            pressed_right:in std_logic;
            pressed_up:in std_logic;
            pressed_down:in std_logic;
            r: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
            g: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
            b: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
            vsync: out std_logic;
            hsync: out std_logic);
end main;

architecture Behavioral of main is

COMPONENT vga
    PORT(   reset: in std_logic;
            vga_clk: in std_logic;
            board_out: in cell_type;
            vsync: out std_logic;
            hsync: out std_logic;
            red: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
            green: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
            blue: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
            hor: out integer range 0 to 799;
            ver: out integer range 0 to 520);
end component;  

COMPONENT clock_divider
    PORT(   clk100:in std_logic;
            reset: in std_logic;
            clk25:out std_logic;
            debouncer_clk:out std_logic);
end component;

COMPONENT debouncer_circuit
    PORT( debouncer_clk:in std_logic;
            p_left:in std_logic;
            p_right:in std_logic;
            p_up:in std_logic;
            p_down:in std_logic;
            direction:out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
end component;

COMPONENT game_logic
    PORT(   clk:in std_logic;
            reset:in std_logic;
            outgame: out game_state;
            direction:in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
            random_food: in unsigned(9 downto 0);
            vsync:in std_logic;
            game_over_reset: out std_logic;
            cell_out:out cell_type;
            hor: in integer range 0 to 799;
            ver: in integer range 0 to 520);
end component;

COMPONENT pseudo_random_generator
    PORT( clk:in std_logic;
            game: in game_state;
            random:out unsigned(9 downto 0));
end component;

FOR ALL: clock_divider USE ENTITY WORK.clock_divider(Behavioral);
FOR ALL: debouncer_circuit USE ENTITY WORK.debouncer_circuit(Behavioral);
FOR ALL: game_logic USE ENTITY WORK.game_logic(Behavioral);
FOR ALL: pseudo_random_generator USE ENTITY WORK.pseudo_random_generator(Behavioral);
FOR ALL: vga USE ENTITY WORK.vga(Behavioral);

signal game: game_state;
signal cell_out:cell_type;
signal clk25:std_logic;
signal gamereset: std_logic:='0';
signal d_clk:std_logic;
signal direction_out:std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal game_over_reset:std_logic:='0';
signal v_sync:std_logic;
signal h_sync:std_logic;
signal randomfood: unsigned(9 downto 0);
signal hor: integer range 0 to 799;
signal ver: integer range 0 to 520;

begin

g1: clock_divider PORT MAP(clk,reset,clk25,d_clk);
g2: debouncer_circuit PORT MAP(d_clk,pressed_left,pressed_right,pressed_up,pressed_down,direction_out);
g3: game_logic PORT MAP(clk25,reset,game,direction_out,randomfood,v_sync,game_over_reset,cell_out,hor,ver);
g4: pseudo_random_generator PORT MAP(clk25,game,randomfood);
g5: vga PORT MAP(gamereset,clk25,cell_out,v_sync,h_sync,r,g,b,hor,ver);

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: but there exists no syntax errors just these warnings and an info about ram and also at synthesis design stucks at optimizing unit game_logic

Comment: Without the context for the various warnings and source for the various blocks the warnings would be associated in your request for help seems destined to degrade into a game of twenty questions, where the eventual outcome may eventually prove unsatisfactory. In other words maybe you aren't being specific enough.  I've seen claims where the 1290 warnings can be generated by opening a project with multiple instances [WARNING:Xst:1290](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/WARNING-Xst-1290-Hierarchical-block-is-unconnected-in-block-lt/td-p/126600 "WARNING:Xst:1290").

Comment: I copied all the files into a new project and the problem continues again. Can it be associated with the following info

INFO:Xst:3019 - HDL ADVISOR - 320 flip-flops were inferred for signal <snake>. You may be trying to describe a RAM in a way that is incompatible with block and distributed RAM resources available on Xilinx devices, or with a specific template that is not supported. Please review the Xilinx resources documentation and the XST user manual for coding guidelines. Taking advantage of RAM resources will lead to improved device usage and reduced synthesis time.

Comment: By the way, I can implement inside modules separately but the game_logic

Answer (score 0):

The 1290 warnings look like your g2, g3, g4 blocks are being optimized out because they don't have any effect on the top level outputs.

The 1710 warning seems to support this hypothesis, saying that there is a mistake (I presume cell_out isn't *supposed* to be constant) somewhere inside one of the blocks that causes the cell_out signal to have a constant value, after which optimization pushed the constant and trimmed everything intended to generate it.

I can't say anything about the 3002 warning without seeing the constituent files.